Use of "nor" when a sentence starts with "not"
Would the following sentence pass for grammatically correct, having regard to its use of "not" and "nor"? I realize "neither" is likely better and there are ways to rewrite the sentence, but I'm curious if this works:

Not the biggest nor the most expensive house on the block, it was nonetheless nice.


"Passes for grammatically correct" and "works" can be two different things. The meaning is certainly clear. The question that's hard to escape is "Why? Why not just use 'or'?"

Yes, this is absolutely correct.
This is definition B2 of Collins Dictionary. Examples of usage include:

I don't want to see him go and nor do the fans.

"Nor" can be used to introduce a second negative statement that follows on or adds to the first, whether or not the first uses "neither".

Yeah, a little literary and unlikely to be heard in everyday conversation, but not surprising in the least.
